# Почему моя модель после привязки к костной структуре ведёт себя странно?

Tags: blender

Сделал скелет, объединил все части персонажа воедино. И за тем сделал привязку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего попробовал поводить рукой и в итоге рука затягивает нижнюю часть плаща, шляпу и глаз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должна ли быть такая реакция? Как её избежать:?

**Файл:** [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v74vh6iwfekmx4q/MagePlayer8.blend?dl=0).

Comment: Как у вас настроена область влияния костей - просто по расстоянию, или же вы сделали скиннинг (т.е. назначили всем вершинам веса влияния на них костей)?

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то настроено через веса. На первом скриншоте указано.

Comment: Вопрос *"через какие веса"*. Если веса авторасчитаны через убывание по квадрату/кубу расстояния, то примерно такой результат и получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автоматические веса не всегда срабатывают корректно. Необходимо поправить вручную.

1. Переведите арматуру в Pose Mode
2. Выделите меш и перейдите в режим Weight Paint.

   В этом режиме можно выделять кости и смотреть влияние кости на меш. Найдите кость, которая неверно влияет на меш. Например:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Далее есть 2 способа удалить ненужный вес.

**1 способ.** Кистью.

1. на панели слева выберите кисть draw и установите вес (weight) на 0

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Затем рисуйте на модели, где вы хотите убрать вес, модель будет возвращаться "на место"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2 способ.** Быстрый.

Существует проблема, что иногда немного веса остается на вершинах, и они немного но двигаются не там где нужно. т.е. нужно очень тщательно удалять вес кистью, а это займет лишнее время. Поэтому есть способ быстрее, но сложнее.

1. Выделите кость которую хотите "обработать"
2. Перейдите в режим Edit Mode
3. Выделите часть меша, на которой хотите убрать вес. Кстати отдельные части меша легко выделять с помощью клавиши <kbd>L</kbd>. Навели мышкой - нажали  <kbd>L</kbd>.
4. На панели Vertex Group нажмите Remove

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Затем снова переходите в режим Vertex Paint, Чтобы проверить результат и выбрать следующую кость.

Небольшая подсказка. Можно упростить себе жизнь, уменьшив количество деформирующих костей. Если какая-то кость техническая, и не оказывает влияние на меш, ее можно убрать из автоматической развесовки, если снять галочку Deform в ее свойствах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]